# What protocols does MS Word Blog Post use to upload to webserver?

Tags: microsoft-word, post, blogging

I would like to investigate and experiment with MS Word Blog Post to a WordPress website.

This is not hosted on WordPress.com!

What protocols does word use for webserver upload?

Can this be setup to work on any web hosting server? (I have a VPS running debian+apache

The instructions to me are short and not particularly helpful for what is required "at the webser end" in order for this to work

Comment: [Setting up Word 2007 for Blogging using the MetaWebLog API](http://www.richardbyrom.com/index.php/weblog/entry/setting-up-word-2007-for-blogging-using-the-metaweblog-api)

Comment: [MetaWebLog API and Blog Writers - Rick Strahl's Web Log](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2007/Mar/10/MetaWebLog-API-and-Blog-Writers)

Comment: thanks David, those links were helpful. I believe that there is a further required element on the webserver for this to work...php-xmlrpc module needs to be installed. I also have a feeling that, based on the articles i read, i need a xmlrpc file installed in the wordpress directory...however, i am not exactly sure yet what file this is?